# "Les hacen" vs. "hacen"

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras

> **Les** hacen muchos regalos.

¿Por qué usamos les"? ¿Podemos decir "Hacen muchos regalos"?

Answer (score 1):

"Hacen muchos regalos" significa que ellos o ellas entregan muchos obsequios, pero al no haber complemento indirecto "les" quien recibe los regalos no está mencionado. No obstante, siempre que alguien hace un regalo, se sobreentiende que alguien más lo recibe.

"Les hacen muchos regalos" puede significar que:

1. Ellos o ellas reciben muchos regalos de otras personas.
2. Ellos o ellas hacen muchos regalos a otras personas.

De acuerdo con (1), la oración tiene un sujeto tácito inespecífico. Se interpreta como una oración impersonal. La oración es semánticamente equivalente a: *Ellos/Ellas reciben muchos regalos.*([Fuente](http://gramaticaespanola.com/publ/las_construcciones_sintacticas_fundamentales/oraciones_activas_pasivas_impersonales_y_medias/sujetos_tacitos_de_interpretacion_inespecifica/45-1-0-735))

De acuerdo con (2), la oración tiene un sujeto tácito específico. Ellos o ellas (personas definidas en el contexto) hacen regalos a otras personas (también definidas en el contexto).

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la opción número 1 (Les=a ellos/ellas)(=reciben) se omite el sujeto en quien recae la ejecución.

- Le(s) hacen regalos (=a ellos/ellas)(¿Quienes? R. Ellos, el colegio, Sus Abuelos, Tíos, Hermanos, etc)
- Les proporcionaban apoyo(=a ellos/a ellas)(¿Quienes? R. Ellos, la institución, etc)
- Les metieron cuatro goles(=a ellos/a ellas)(¿Quién/Quienes? R. Ellos, el equipo, etc)
- Les metimos cuatro goles(=a ellos/a ellas)(¿Quién/Quienes? R. Nosotros, etc)
- Les llegó un grito(=a ellos/ellas)(¿De quién? R. No se sabe)
- Les hemos dado/Les dimos(=a ellos)(¿Quiénes? R. Nosotros)
- Les ha dado por comprar/Les dio por comprar(=a ellos)

La numéro 2 (=hacen) sólo la he escuchado recientemente. No se si es incorrecto o no o si es algo que está para quedarse, no me suena mal, tampoco se lo adjudico a alguien en particular para no caer en estereotipos o ser prejuicioso, no me suena mal pero para mí lo usual es decir:

- Hacen muchos regalos(se sobreentiende el 'ellos' y se omite en quien recae)

Obviamente, todo debe estar dentro de un contexto, si digo:

- Como aquellos padres que les hacen a sus hijos regalos caros para compensar su ausencia.

Acá perfectamente puedo omitir 'les' porque se sobreentiende que se vincula con su duplicación 'a sus', pero le da un matiz y considero obviamente incorrecto utilizar el pronombre 'le' en su lugar para referirise al complemento indirecto.